# Networkx installed but not working Spyder python 3.7.9

Tags: python, networkx, spyder

I have successfully installed networkx using the command prompt:

```
    Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\users\amelie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5,>=4.3 in c:\users\amelie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from networkx) (4.4.2)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqOyc.png

But whenever i try to use it in spyder, this message prompts and i can't  figure how to solve this:

```
File "C:\Users\amelie\Documents\•ESIR\Alg\TP\TP2\1-networkX exemples\Exemple1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import networkx as nx

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvNpk.png

please help me :')

Comment: Hello, how did you install spyder? With Anaconda?

Comment: Hi, I don't remember, but no not with anaconda. Maybe just a standalone installer i guess

Comment: My unsure guess would be that your Spyder is using a different python interpreter than the one in your cmd. Meaning you are installing for a certain interpreter but using another one under spyder. So maybe check under tools>preferences>Python Interpreter, and set "Use the following python interpreter" to the one you're using in cmd (to know where it is, you can either type `where python`, or maybe check "C:\Program Files\Python<version>\python.exe").

Comment: You can also try to install it directly without changing the interpreter by typing `pip install networkx` directly in your spyder console :)

Comment: 1/2 Ok so i've tried to change the interpreter with the path i have from `where python` , but it says `Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.10.0 and < 1.11.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:

pip install spyder‑kernels` so i did it in cmd, and all seems to be already installed... ("requirements already satisfied" with all componants, and at the right path)

Comment: 2/2 and this shows up when i leave the interpreter as default, and try to write a command  directly into the Spyder console: _'C:\Program' isn't recognized as an internal or external command, a program or command file._ (i typed `pip install networkx`)

Comment: 1/2 Ok I see, have you tried pip install spyder-kernels==1.10.0 ? Because actually, I guess that this could be where your error comes from. And for your 2/2, I suppose that it comes from the fact that the path to pip is "C:\Program Files\<something>" with a space and that it doesn't appreciate it. Otherwise, last solution would be to install anaconda (spyder is provided automatically) and then you'll be able to do `pip install networkx` in your Spyder console. I feel that anaconda is one of the best package and environment manager to start with, I used it for a long time. Bonne chance :)

Comment: Thanks, i tried with "pip install spyder-kernels==1.10.0" and it worked !